# Laravel - How to run something before a flash session is forgotten

Tags: php, ajax, session, laravel

I have created a form that user can upload your profile avatar (photo) using ajax request.

In the edit mode, when user choose some image and send to serve, i move it to my temp directory and create a flash session to record the file reference (and i send the response to the client with the path to display the photo).

```
Session::flash( 'avatarTemp', [ 'name' => $temp['name'] ] );
```

So, yet in edit mode, whenever the user select a new image i just get the reference to the previous file and delete it.

The problem is when the flash session is broken in another user action as close page, for example. In this case i have no more reference to the file that i could delete.

The ideal for me would run the instruction to delete current file every time the flash session is forgotten. Can i do?

Or there's another way instead flash session to solve this situation?

**I FOUND AN ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION TO ABOVE PROBLEM**

At the core, my problem was to display user selected image but no attach it to her model. To make this, i don't need to send the file to the server. Now i'm using javascript [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).